# non-causal cascade filtering process in frequency domain

Tags: finite-impulse-response, frequency-domain, overlap-save

if i have linear filter that operate in frequency domain filter length is L

(Overlap and save method)
if there is no computational time, i get L input signal and fft and multiply filter and ifft

the output is L sample after L time index

in this case, i think the frequency domain filter could be non-causal filter because i use corrected input data (past and present data)

my question is if i operate signal processing in time domain and frequency domain

if i have to pass 3 filter (filter length L)

in time domain

3*L/2 delay is need because each of filter have L/2 group delay

in frequency domain

only L sample delay because of non-causal filter in frequeny domain (only real value) whatever how many filter is conneted

Comment: No, FFT based filtering is causal. You have no output until nfft samples are ready for computation.

Comment: please add to your question a simple 4 sample example of what you are suggesting with the specific time line of what occurs after each step, in actual implementation (show this graphically and I think you will see the answer for yourself or we can help point out the confusion).   If you need to extend this to overlap-save then do that for 12 samples of 4 sample blocks